# yii2 AdminLTE Header Menu works only on Site Controller

Tags: yii2

I have successfully integrated adminLTE template. Why is it that the header menu only works when on the site controller. When on other controller, it does not work..

```
http://localhost/kalahi/frontend/web/index.php?r=site
```

[image]

```
http://localhost/kalahi/frontend/web/index.php?r=reminder
```

[image]

Comment: what error you getting in console.

Comment: Im not getting any error in console.

Comment: I'm unable to give solution until you post your code. Kindly refer: https://github.com/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. There was a conflict in the js files.